# Proof that $\|IS\|=\|I\|^n$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to understand part of a proof given in Marcus's Number Fields of the following theorem:

> Let $K$ be a number field and let $L$ be a number field of degree $n$ over $K$. Let $R$ be the integer ring for $K$ and $S$ be the integer ring for $L$. Let $I$ be an ideal in $R$. Then for the $S$-ideal $IS$, $\|IS\|=\|I\|^n$.

It is sufficient to prove this for the case in which $I$ is a prime $P$. The general result will follow from factoring $I$ into primes. It's not hard to see that $S/PS$ is a vector space over the field $R/P$. The claim is that the dimension is $n$. First we show the dimension is at most $n$. Fixing $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_{n+1}$, we must show the corresponding elements in $S/PS$ are linearly dependent over $R/P$. We know $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_{n+1}$ are linearly dependent over $K$, and also over $R$. Thus $b_1\alpha_1+\cdots b_{n+1}\alpha_{n+1}=0$ for some $b_i\in R$, not all zero. We must show the $b_i$ need not all be in $P$.

We have a lemma: Let $A$ and $B$ be nonzero ideals in a Dedekind domain $R$, with $B\subset A$ and $A\neq R$. Then there exists a $\gamma\in K$ such that $\gamma B\subset R$, $\gamma B\not\subset A$.

I want to apply this lemma to $A=P$ and $B=(b_1,...,b_{n+1}$) and hopefully derive a contradiction. But I'm not sure how to proceed. What should follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if we multiply
$$
b_1\alpha_1+\dots+b_{n+1}\alpha_{n+1} = 0
$$
by $\gamma$, we get
$$
\gamma b_1\alpha_1+\dots+\gamma b_{n+1}\alpha_{n+1} = 0.
$$
We know that $\gamma b_k \in R$. Now if they all were in $P$, then the whole $\gamma B$ would be in $P$ which is forbidden by the lemma. So, we have found a trivial linear combination with coefficients from $R/P$ at least one of which is non-zero, as desired.